# Delete last word in each line in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to go through a file, and delete the last word in each line. Currently, I am using the command

```
sed 's/^*\n//' old.txt > new.txt
```

but it is coming out that old.txt is the same as new.txt. Thanks for any help, and let me know if I can clarify the question. Also, in order to define 'word' I am just using spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following. `\w*` matches the last word inside of the file and `$` anchors the search to the end of the line.

```
sed s/'\w*$'// old.txt > new.txt
```

The reason that old.txt is coming out as new.txt is likely because your regular expression `^*\n` is not matching any lines in old.txt.

Comment: +1, the `g` is unnecessary because the regex can only match once per line anyway.

Comment: Edited to remove the g at the end (force of habit). For those that do not know, the /g allows multiple matches per line.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is simpler than I thought it would be.

Comment: this just deletes the last character. depending on your definition of word you might want to use `\w\+` or `\S\+` instead

Answer (score 1):

The following is an inline edit. PRIOR TO RUNNING ANYTHING PLEASE BACKUP YOUR FILE.

```
sed -i 's/[[:alnum:]]*$//' /yourfile
```

If you are working on OS X, you may want to try the following

```
sed -i '' 's/[[:alnum:]]*$//' /yourfile
```

If you are not interested in writing directly back to the original file, but would like the output to be printed.

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]]*$//' /yourfile
```